# How to efficiently compare the items in a list within a dictionary to the 0th item within another list within a second dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I have two dictionaries. One dictionary has a list of values, as shown below:

```
d1 = {10: [123, 244, 222], 13: [109, 125]}
```

In this dictionary, for the most part there is only one item in the list, but there are a few that contain multiple values.

The second dictionary also has a list of values. But for each value within this list, there are multiple values. So essentially my second dictionary contains a list of lists, as shown below:

```
d2 = {125: [[120, 244, 222], [177, 134, 111], [123, 11, 344]], 123: [[125, 109, 180], [123, 156, 290]]}
```

What I'm trying to do is efficiently compare all the values in `d1` with all the values in position 0, for each list within all the keys in `d2`.

For instance, I'd like to compare every single value in `d1`, with the following values of `d2: (120, 177, 123, 125, 123)` as these represent the 0th values in all the lists. I'd then like to store the list whose 0th value matches a value in `d1`.

For some reason indexing isn't working for me. I've been trying this:

```
 for key, value in d1.iteritems():                                           
     for list in value:                                                                                      
         for key, value2 in d2.iteritems():                
             for item2 in value2:  
                 if list == item2[0]:        
                     d3[item2[0]].append(item2[0:])
```

And get this output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {125: [[125, 109, 180]], 123: [[123, 11, 344], [123, 156, 290]]})
```

But the dictionaries that I've used in this example are much smaller than my actual dictionaries. One has hundreds of thousands of lines of data and the other has millions.

One thing I haven't incorporated into my code is iterating through keys only if they have matching keys.

I've started off with something like:

```
for key in d1.iterkeys() and d2.iterkeys():
```

But ran into issues using the following:

```
if d1[key][:] == d2[key][:][:][0]
```

because of the whole issue with having a list of lists. This part was very frustrating. If I can iterate without having to explicitly use this part of my code (for list in value:) shown above and just do a value index it would save time I believe. But indexing hasn't been working for me. For instance, using `d2[key][:][:][0]`, I always get (for my second dictionary specifically) the first list within the key, rather than the first value for each list within the key.

**EDIT: Until I get updates on the two answers below I'm working this code here, which is basically the same as my initial code except I've added a conditional statement where I check to see if the keys are equal. Does it makes sense to add in the conditional statement in terms of making the search quicker? I don't know if adding the if statement will slow it down more than searching only where the keys match will speed it up.**

```
for key1, value1 in d1.iteritems():                                           
     for item1 in value1:                                                                                      
         for key2, value2 in d2.iteritems():  
             if key1 == key2:              
                 for item2 in value2:  
                     if list == item2[0]:        
                         d3.append(item2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my go at it:

```
from itertools import chain

d1 = {10: [123, 244, 222], 13: [109, 125]}
d2 = {125: [[120, 244, 222], [177, 134, 111], [123, 11, 344]], 123: [[125, 109, 180], [123, 156, 290]]}

# Flatten out the list using a list comprehension
key_values = [values for list in d1.values() for values in list]

new_dict = dict()
for d2_list in chain.from_iterable(d2.itervalues()):
    key_to_check = d2_list[0]
    if key_to_check in key_values:
        if key_to_check in new_dict:
            new_dict[key_to_check].append(d2_list)
        else:
            new_dict[key_to_check] = [d2_list]
print new_dict
```

This should be at least somewhat faster due to the fact that we are only looping over the second dictionary's values using an iterator.
I use chain.from_iterable to flatten out the list of iterators from the itervalues call.

Now for the actual search, I just check if the current 'key' (element at index 0) is within our flattened list of values from d1.
Try it out with your large dataset, and see if it's any faster than your current solution.

Comment: My data is too large to do a test run but I do believe it would be faster for the reason you stated. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The most explicit way to do it will be:

```
d1 = {10: [123, 244, 222], 13: [109, 125]}

d2 = {125: [[120, 244, 222], [177, 134, 111], [123, 11, 344]], 123: [[125, 109, 180], [123, 156, 290]]}

for key1 in d1:
    for val1 in d1[key1]:
        for key2 in d2:
            for vals2 in d2[key2]:
                 val2 = vals2[0]
                 if val1 == val2:
                     print "equal"
```

Of course instead of just printing that they are equal do whatever you need with `key1`, `key2`, `val1` and `val2`.

Comment: Okay. This works. You didn't use .iteritems(). Does that make the process any quicker? And is there any way of getting out using as many for loops?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the values for d2 are all list of list

```
d1 = {10: [123, 244, 222], 13: [109, 125]}
d2 = {125: [[120, 244, 222], [177, 134, 111], [123, 11, 344]], 123: [[125, 109, 180], [123, 156, 290]]}

d1Flat = [i for item in d1.values() for i in item]
d2Flat = [i for item in d2.values() for i in item]

res = []

for lst in d2Flat:
    if lst[0] in d1Flat:
        res.append(lst)
```

Comment: This also works. My only concern is that since my data is very large, I don't know that I want to make more dictionaries ( d1Flat and d2Flat).